# Openlayers - rotate feature (line, polygon) on map

Tags: angular, typescript, gis, openlayers

I am trying to achieve an option to rotate the object on map, when it is selected and additional button is pressed.
I have tried to integrate code, that is provided in [Openlayers examples](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/modify-scale-and-rotate.html), but got no luck with that, because I can't find a way, how can I use that modify interaction with a certain object from map (that user has selected by clicking on it.

Another alternative I have tried, is ol-ext module approach of rotating a feature, but in that [example](http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/interaction/map.interaction.transform.html), I also can't find a way, how to specify selected polygon to rotate it.

Can someone, who has achieved this, share knowledge on how to do this, or at best, share some code snippets with signle object rotation?

To be clear- rotation I want to get is by user physically rotating the object with a mouse.

Comment: Check the documentation you either pass a source to Modify or a collecation of features you like to modify: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_interaction_Modify-Modify.html

Comment: Yes, I already tried that too, but still no results. @BR75

Comment: You need to provide your code